# Disable options in v-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to disable options in v-autocomplete? I did see this `item-disabled` and passed the string value of the option it didn't work.
code snippet

```
<v-autocomplete
    :items="states"
    item-text="name"
    label="State"
    item-disabled="Florida"
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<v-autocomplete
    :items="states"
    item-text="name"
    label="State"
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

Simply add a disabled prop to your Object:

```
 states: [
    {
      name: "New York", disabled: true
    },
    {
      name: "Florida"
    },
    {
      name: "Texas"
    },
  ]
```

You could populate that property dynamicly depending on what you want to be disabled.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRXrJL?editors=1111